# How do i find out which TextView is connected to which array?

Tags: android, arrays, for-loop, textview

I would like to set the background of an TextView inside of a for-loop.
But because you can't use arrays as names for the TextViews i don't know how to do this.

```
findViewById(R.id.array[x]).setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ffb6c1"));
```

my TextViews are called: array1, array2, array3...

And i would like to put the numbers instead of the [x]. 
Like this:

```
for (int x=1;x<13;x++){
    findViewById(R.id.array[x]).setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ffb6c1"));
}
```

How can i do this?

Comment: are you saving your `TextView` id in array?

Comment: No, i have got Strings in the arrays ( array[1],array[2],array[3]...)
Those arrays are shown in the TextViews (array1,array2,array3...)
I would like to automatically assign the connected array to the right array.
array[1] = array1 
array[2] = array2

But the numbers for the Textviews (array1,array2,array3...) should automatically be added. array[1] should be changed into array1 etc.

Comment: are those `TextViews` exists in the XML?

Comment: Yes
I only want to change their background

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try as follows...

```
Resources res = getResources();

for (int x = 1; x < 13; x++){

    int id = res.getIdentifier("array" + x, "id", getContext().getPackageName());
    findViewById(id).setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ffb6c1"));
}
```